# Create tableview like as iOS Calendar

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift4, fscalendar

I'm trying to create a calendar like as Google or iOS has. For calendar I'm using amazing FSCalendar. It work perfectly. But I have a problem with tableview for day events. I created uitableview with timeline (1 cell = 30 minutes). But how to add events to here that look like Google or iOS calendar, for example
[image]

I think I need to add buttons for each events and add it to uitableview.
This is my code:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return (hour_end - hours_begin) * step
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    cell.timeLabel.layer.zPosition = 1
    cell.timeLabel.isHidden = true

    if indexPath.row % step == 0 && indexPath.row != ((hour_end - hours_begin) * step) - 1 {
        let hour = indexPath.row / step + hours_begin
        cell.timeLabel.text = (hour < 10 ? "0": "") + String(hour) + ":00"
        cell.timeLabel.layer.zPosition = 10
        cell.timeLabel.isHidden = false
        cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 50, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }
    else {
        cell.timeLabel.text = ""
        cell.timeLabel.isHidden = true
        cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 2000, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        cell.timeLabel.layer.zPosition = 1
    }

    add_event(indexPath: indexPath, nRef: 5, offset: 0, height: 64.0)

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(indexPath.row)
}

func add_event(indexPath: IndexPath, nRef: Int, offset: CGFloat, height: CGFloat)
{
    let row = indexPath.row
    let rectOfCellInTableViewCoordinates = tableView.rectForRow(at: indexPath)
    let rectOfCellInSuperviewCoordinates = view.convert(rectOfCellInTableViewCoordinates, to: tableView.superview)
    print("\(row) \(rectOfCellInSuperviewCoordinates.origin.x) \(rectOfCellInSuperviewCoordinates.origin.y)")
    if row == nRef {
        if let z = view.viewWithTag(nRef) as! UIButton?{
            print("z found")
            z.removeFromSuperview()
        }

        let btn_x = 50
        let btn_width = tableView.frame.width - 50
        let frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(btn_x), y: rectOfCellInSuperviewCoordinates.origin.y + offset, width: btn_width, height: height)
        let overlay_btn = UIButton(frame: frame)

        overlay_btn.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.5, green: 0.0, blue: 0.5, alpha: 0.3)
        overlay_btn.setTitle("Press for more details", for: .normal)
        overlay_btn.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
        overlay_btn.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        overlay_btn.tag = 5
        tableView.addSubview(overlay_btn)

    }
}
```

But, I think it is not great solution. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using a scroll view for what you are trying to accomplish. Instead of using cells and adding views... splitting them up between cells will be tricky. Instead, you can have your scroll view that has all of the dividers and hour marks.

Implement a custom UIView that will serve as an event. When the user creates an event, it will be a subview of your scrollview. Say for example your scrollview is 2400px long and each hour is 100px, If the event starts at 12pm, add the UIView to the 1200px mark...

That is a rough explanation of how I would approach this problem. Feel free to reach out if you have further questions.

Comment: In that scroll view I should add lines, timelines and etc. Does it work fast?

Comment: @dim can you clarify your question?

Comment: You recommended to me create scrollView and add on it all buttons, images, label etc. It will be created new on every day in month when user click on the day in calendar. Does it fast and safe solution?

Comment: @Dim well, everything will be instantiated as soon as the view is loaded unlike a tableview that will dequeue views one by one. I think that since it is such a small view it will be fast and as long as you follow best practices it will be safe.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I came back to this task and did scroll with time line and events very fast! It is so easy and fast solution.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that @Dim!